# If body has fullpagejs class play video youtube api

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, fullpage.js

I am using Fullpage.js and my first slide has a youtube video that autoplays using youtube embedded api. When I scroll to the next slide I have noticed that the video stops playing, I would like it to continue.

I am trying to check if the body has the class "fp-viewing-home" which is generated by fullpage.js when the first slide is active. Then if body has class play video.

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
var homeSlide = document.getElementsByClassName("fp-viewing-home")[0];

function hasClass(body, homeSlide) {
    event.target.playVideo();
}
```

I would like if the first slide in displaying the video to continue to play, else pause video

Comment: `..the video to continue to play, else pause video`; else...what? When do you want the video to continue and when do you want it to pause?

Comment: @AdrianPop thanks for replying, i do not know why the video stops playing, and i would like it to continue playing at all times to be honest. how do i make sure that the video dose not stop?

Comment: turns out fullpage js has a stopmedia function which i disabled, and this fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

According to [fullpage.js documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#pause-on-leave):

> **Pause on leave**
>   Embedded HTML5  /  and Youtube iframes are automatically paused when you navigate away from a section or slide. **This can be disabled by using the attribute data-keepplaying. For example:**

```
<audio data-keepplaying>
    <source src="http://metakoncept.hr/horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
```